# Change meaning of various multitouch gestures on macbook pro

Tags: macbook

Is there any way to change the meaning of the multitouch mouse gestures on the macbook pro?

There are 4-finger gestures that it handles, but it looks like the meanings are hard-coded.  4-fingers up/down trigger expose, and left/right work like command-tab.

I'd really love to change one of those to open Spaces.

I'd also love to be able to add a 3-finger click to simulate a middle-mouse-button click (for opening links in new tabs in firefox).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spent some more time looking through google and managed to find one that appears to work exactly the way I want:

http://lifehacker.com/5435445/bettertouchtool-customizes-your-macs-multitouch-gestures

I turned off the default 4-finger swipe handling and was able to add 4-finger up as spaces and 4-finger down as expose.  Was also able to define 3-finger click as Command-click (which is what's actually used in FF to open a new tab).

Answer (score 0):

One utility that'll do this is [MultiClutch](http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/27016/multiclutch), which appears to be in perpetual beta, but nonetheless gets good reviews.

Comment: I saw that one, but a couple posts suggested problems with 10.6 (though maybe those comments were out of date).  But even then, it seems to only let you define keyboard combinations to the gestures.  I could accomplish most things with that, but I think I like BTT's buit-in special commands like Spaces and Expose, and its ability to do mouse clicks.